# FB login using Facebook SDK php 4.0.9 and Chrome

Tags: php, facebook-login

I am trying to integrate the new FB php SDK version 4.0.9 - everything seems pretty straight forward except one thing which I cannot manage to figure out.
The Facebook login using the **Chrome browser** needs two tries - I do not know why. I echoed every single step, even monitored my sessions - nothing stands out.
This are the exact steps to reproduce the bug for the code bellow:

- log-out from Facebook, close the chrome browser, access the code page, click login, login to Facebook. After being brought back to the redirect page - no session is created.
- login again - it works
- this problem becomes more frustrating because if I logout from Facebook after a successful login and try again without exiting the browser, everything works fine.

It does not happen with Firefox!

I am using this version: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0

!! 4.0.9. extremely different usage than 4.0.0

```
<?php

session_start();

$appid = 'appid';
$appsecret = 'appsecret';



require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );

require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/SignedRequest.php' );

require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSignedRequestFromInputHelper.php' ); // added in v4.0.9
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );

// these two classes required for canvas and tab apps
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookCanvasLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookPageTabHelper.php' );

require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );

use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;

use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\Entities\SignedRequest;

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookSignedRequestFromInputHelper; // added in v4.0.9
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

// these two classes required for canvas and tab apps
use Facebook\FacebookCanvasLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookPageTabHelper;

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( $appid,$appsecret );

// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://mypage/code.php' );

// see if a existing session exists
if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
  // create new session from saved access_token
  $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );

  // validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
  try {
    if ( !$session->validate() ) {
      $session = null;
    }
  } catch ( Exception $e ) {
    // catch any exceptions
    $session = null;
  }
}  

if ( !isset( $session ) || $session === null ) {
  // no session exists
    echo 'case 0<br/>';

  try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
  } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
    // When Facebook returns an error
    // handle this better in production code
    echo 'case 1<br/>';
    print_r( $ex );
  } catch( Exception $ex ) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    // handle this better in production code
    echo 'case 2<br/>';
    print_r( $ex );
  }

}
 echo ' avem session? == '.($session ? '1':'0').' == <br/>';
// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  echo 'case 3<br/>';
  // save the session
  $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
  if($_SESSION['fb_token']) echo 'avem $_SESSION <br/>';
  // create a session using saved token or the new one we generated at login
  $session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );

  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();

  // print profile data
  echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>';

  // print logout url using session and redirect_uri (logout.php page should destroy the session)
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLogoutUrl( $session, 'http://mypage/logout' ) . '">Logout</a>';

} else {
    echo 'case 4<br/>';
  // show login url
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'email', 'user_friends' ) ) . '">Login</a>';
}


echo '<br/><br/>';


print_r($_SESSION);
```